# How to limit the download speed after first N mb in Squid?

Tags: squid, bandwidth, network-speed

In my network, when someone is downloading big files, the internet speed is going down for everyone else.

So what I want to do is, when someone starts downloading a file, he will download first 5 megabytes with normal speed, then the speed will go down, for example, to 100kbps.

Is it possible to do it in Squid 2.7?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your set up, and I don't know squid, and I am not sure that it's as configurable as you need but you could always try 'Trickle'. If you have the a ability you can enforce a policy whereby users use their internet accessing programs through Trickle.

It can be used like this (perhaps through a shell script):

```
trickle -d 20 -u 5 wget -c http://mydownloads.com/bigfile.zip
```

This will start 'wget' with the specified options and enforce a maximum download speed of 20kbps and an upload speed of 5kbps while it runs. Of course it can be any other application, it doesn't have to be wget.

**[Update]: Have a read of this page: [Squid Proxy Server Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20131201210316/http://www.ehow.com/how_7588578_squid-proxy-server-tutorial.html) Specifically check out point 4. It seems to detail exactly what you're after.**

Comment: I am using pfSense and i found bandwidth throttling. However, it is limited to limiting the bandwidth to a certain speed. What i want make is doing the same thing after for example 5mb of downloading on full speed.

Comment: See the link above. That appears to show how to do exactly that using Squid. (At the bottom of my answer)

Comment: Oh I see that! Thank you :) Here is another good [one](http://www.howtoforge.com/squid-delay-pools-bandwidth-management)